# Vagrant gpg communication being blocked

Tags: vagrant

hope someone can help me. I recently purchased Rapid Application Development with CakePHP 2.0 by Jose Diaz-Gonzalez and I have been struggling to set up vagrant.

I am using the latest version of virtual-box, vagrant and chef and I am following the instructions to the letter, hower I am receiving the following error:

```
==> default: [2015-03-12T07:46:39+00:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /var/chef/cache/chef-stacktrace.out
==> default: [2015-03-12T07:46:39+00:00] ERROR: execute[request git key] (/tmp/vagrant-chef/bd885c961fe7ceaf386b7954711e7941/cookbooks/apt/providers/repository.rb line 2) had an error: Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed: Expected process to exit with [0], but received '2'
==> default: ---- Begin output of gpg --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys E1DF1F24 ----
==> default: STDOUT: 
==> default: STDERR: gpg: keyring `/root/.gnupg/secring.gpg' created
==> default: gpg: requesting key E1DF1F24 from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com
==> default: gpg: keyserver timed out
==> default: gpg: keyserver receive failed: keyserver error
==> default: ---- End output of gpg --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys E1DF1F24 ----
==> default: Ran gpg --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys E1DF1F24 returned 2
==> default: [2015-03-12T07:46:39+00:00] FATAL: Chef::Exceptions::ChildConvergeError: Chef run process exited unsuccessfully (exit code 1)

Chef never successfully completed! Any errors should be visible in the
output above. Please fix your recipes so that they properly complete.
```

My Stack trace shows the following:

```
Generated at 2015-03-12 08:06:25 +0000
Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed: execute[request git key] (/tmp/vagrant-chef/bd885c961fe7ceaf386b7954711e7941/cookbooks/apt/providers/repository.rb line 2) had an error: Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed: Expected process to exit with [0], but received '2'
---- Begin output of gpg --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys E1DF1F24 ----
STDOUT:
STDERR: gpg: keyring `/root/.gnupg/secring.gpg' created
gpg: requesting key E1DF1F24 from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com
gpg: keyserver timed out
gpg: keyserver receive failed: keyserver error
---- End output of gpg --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys E1DF1F24 ----
Ran gpg --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys E1DF1F24 returned 2
```

I have established that this is caused by port 11371 being blocked by our corporate network. I have read somewhere that you can force gpg to use port 80, but the problem is that the python directory is obviously not accessable until "Variant up" has run. This is a bit of a catch 22, unless someone out there knows a way to bypass or fix this issue?

Comment: Just received access to the port and ip, so now it works perfectly. Still going to try any solutions posted so that we can help those that stay blocked. Anyone from Vagrant or Friends willing to comment?

Answer (score 0):

Search for the following line in your Chef cookbook

```
command "gpg --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys #{new_resource.key}"
```

and change it to

```
command "gpg --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys #{new_resource.key}"
```

Comment: Thanks Railslide, unfortunately that produces the same error? As fate would have it, the tech department unblocked that port and ip for me. And now it works perfectly.